# Словарь синонимов не выдает нужный результат

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

В приложении используется rails 4.2 и стандартный гем elasticsearch
Для поиска понадобился дополнительный фильтр по синонимам. Был написан словарик и фильтр по [документации](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). Но почему то не все слова из словаря корректно ищутся.

```
'апач, апачи, апаче => Apache'
'пхп => PHP'
'гит, гитхаб => Git'
'линукс => Linux'
'клиент-сервер => Client-Server'
'питон, пайтон, python3, python2 => Python'
```

Такого формата словарик написанный в отдельном файле.

```
synonym: {
        type: 'synonym',
        synonyms: Rails.root.join('config', 'elastic', 'synonyms_dictionary.txt').readlines.map(&:strip).join(',')
         },
```

и таким образом выглядит его внедрение в фильтр

Суть проблемы в том, что по каким то причинам некорректно ведет себя поиск по синонимам. Например\по примерам из словаря\,`гит - не находит записей`, но `гитхаб - находит записи по слову git`,`питон|пайтон|python3 - не ищет записи`, но `python2 - находит записи по слову python`. `Линукс находит записи включающие слово Linux`.
И это очень странно и не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось ему не нравился метод встраивания. То есть он принимает таким образом, что одна строка синонимов = один запрос. Тк я удалял все переносы строк все писалось в 1 строчку и соответственно нарушало логику работы, а эластик проглатывал и работал некорректно.
Решение изменить внедрения строку на:
`synonyms:[Rails.root.join('config','elastic','synonyms_dictionary.txt').readlines.join(',')]`